# Java Swing unable to display

Tags: java, swing

I have created and JFRAMe with two fields , UserName and Password.
This Dones not have the main funciton.

WCreated another file with Main funciton.

I have created an "ok" button and it would take the input from the username and password fields and do the control from the main.

Please see the code bloe

```
package testswing;

/**
 *
 * @author sumanshreeansh
 */
public class TestSwing {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        LoginForm form = new LoginForm();

        form.setVisible(true);
        String username =  form.getUserName();
        String password = form.getPassword();

        System.out.println("The va;lues of username and password"+ username+ " "+ password);
    }

}
```

The JFRAME

```
package testswing;

/**
 *
 * @author sumanshreeansh
 */
public class LoginForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {



    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form LoginForm
     */
    public LoginForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Password");

        jLabel2.setText("User Name");

        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("OK");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 99, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(46, 46, 46))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(147, 147, 147))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addContainerGap(256, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(205, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(45, 45, 45)))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(76, 76, 76)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 64, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(55, 55, 55))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addContainerGap(195, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(200, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(37, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String uname = jTextField2.getText();
        setUserName(uname);

        String password = jPasswordField1.getText();

        setPassword(password);



        System.out.println("The vaules of Uanme and password"+ getUserName() + " "+ getPassword());

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LoginForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

When I click on the okay button the control should go to the class
public class TestSwing and execute from there now it is giving the output as "NULL"....Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `JFrame#setVisible`, the system will wonder off and prepare the window and show it at some point in the future, BUT, it will return immediately, meaning, when you ask for the user name password from the frame, the user has not yet had a chance to actually enter anything into the field.

There are a number of ways you could achieve this, but what you probably want is a modal `JDialog`, which will block at the point it's made visible until it's closed

See [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details